# Replace tab in NSString with \t

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, nsstring, sbjson

I'm parsing json with SBJson.
I receive an error "-JSONValue failed. Error is: Unescaped control character [0x09]" when parsing my json string, it has unencoded tab. How to replace this tab in my json string to \t? If i remove tab manualy, everything is good. Or how to encode this tab properly?

Comment: When I convert Json to nsstring, all \n, \t, \r are hidden. how did you get them to display so you can convert them?

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to coolcool1994's question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`:

```
NSString * newJsonString = [oldJsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"\\t"];
```