# Is there a way to convert tabs (\t) into white space before loading into an NSString?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace tab in NSString with \t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400514/replace-tab-in-nsstring-with-t)

As per the title: is there a way to convert tabs (`\t`) into white space when loading a text file into an NSString? I am trying to convert a text file and they're giving me trouble.

Comment: @H2CO3 hehe fair enough. I was actually looking for a convinience method that would save me from doing it manually.

Comment: @Dionysis In this case, I revoked my downvote, but next time please be precise and make sure you specify that you've seen the documentation and found something but you're dissatisfied with that.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
NSString *test = @"hi\tsecond column\t";
NSString *stringWithWhiteSpace = [test stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\t" withString: @" ";
```

`test` is just a test string that would be the text file you're loading. `stringWithWhiteSpace` is the string with white space instead of tabs.